# Negative lookahead to parse HTML

Tags: php, regex, negative-lookbehind

I've got a pattern like that:

```
/<img([^>]*?)(?!\sdata-src=([\'\"])[\S\h\v]*?\2)\ssrc=([\'\"])([\S\h\v]*?)\3/igm
```

And that's what I want to achieve:

```
<img src="test'"/> # this should be matched, and it is
<img data-src="abc" src="abc"/> # this one shouldn't be matched, but it is
```

I don't understand why do my negative-lookahead is not working - as you can see I don't want the `data-src` parameter to appear before the `src` parameter.

To test my expressions I'm using regex101 and my example is based on it. I'll be using that regex in PHP.

To satisfy the PHP community:

```
$html = '<img src="test\'"/><img data-src="abc" src="abc"/>';
$html = preg_replace('/<img([^>]*?)(?!\sdata-src=([\'\"])[\S\h\v]*?\2)\ssrc=([\'\"])([\S\h\v]*?)\3/i', '<img$1 data-src=$3$4$3 src=$3placeholder$3', $html);
echo $html;
>>> <img data-src="test'" src="placeholder"/><img data-src="abc" src="abc"/>
```

Comment: Please show your actual input along with expected output. And regex is not the correct tool to parse HTML

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia If you want me to use DOMDocument or other things I'll say simply - no. I can not rely on libxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `([^>]*?)` messed it up. Try.

```
<img (?!data-src=['"])[^>]*?src=(['"])(.*?)\1
```

see https://regex101.com/r/wKQk4p/1

Comment: but it won't work when there will be other parameters before `src` (even non-proper), that's why I've placed the `([^>]*?)` there